# Nested union types in F#

Tags: f#, types

Is there any way to crate nested union types in F#? Something like this

```
type MainType =
    | A of
        | AA of int
        | AB of float
    | B of int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to separate the types(as in kvb's post). <strike>I have heard of plans to add polymorphic variance (as in ocaml) to F#</strike>, which would allow you to do something similar.

In ocaml,

```
type mainType =
    | A of [ `AA of int | `AB of float ]
    | B of int
```

Comment: There are currently no plans to add polymorphic variance to F#. (Which IIRC means having a nested discriminated union, correct?)

Comment: Yeah. It allows for that, and thanks for clearing up that rumor, Chris.

Comment: I thought that any OCaml code was compilable with #light off, which means that that ought to work...

Comment: Sure, everything but: Monomorphic types, Functors, Structural subtyping, Polymorphic variants, Recursive types, Recursive modules, Typesetting (the Format module), Macros (camlp4), Non-int numeric literals in patterns... and I'm sure a lot more.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think so.  The doesn't seem to be much advantage over creating two separate union types like:

```
type NestedType =
| AA of int
| AB of float

type MainType =
| A of NestedType
| B of int

let mainValue = A (AA 1)
```

Comment: I don't have to invent nested type name :)